# Upload dialog is not shown when button.click()

Tags: javascript, file-upload, click

I am writing one automation tool and I want to open upload file dialog. Suppose this page:  http://www.ulozto.cz/upload

When I execute:

```
document.getElementsByName('upfile_0')[0].click()
```

It does not show upload dialog. Is there any way to handle this in JS, or is this possibility blocked for some security reasons ? I tried dispatching some click events, but it did not help. I am not owner of page, so I cannot change source code, I can only play with JS on client side.

Comment: Where are you executing the JS? You said you don't own the page.

Comment: I am using CEF Chromium Embedit Framework, but same results can be obtained from fe Chrome console @Ting Sun

Comment: I think due to sandboxing you can't trigger an upload dialog using JS from client side. Not 100% sure though. Are you sure your selector is getting something back?

Comment: Yes, it returns correct element @Ting Sun